# How to convert mysql_result to mysqli result in this example

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I understand how to fetch a result in mysqli, but how would this example be coded for mysqli?

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
    $uname = mysql_result($result, $i, "username");
    $email = mysql_result($result, $i, "email");

    echo "<tr><td>$uname</td><td>$email</td></tr>\n";
}
```

Thanks for taking a look

Comment: You really should read the MySQLi docs. You'll need to change more than that line. Your mysql_connect, mysql_query, etc. stuff all needs replacement.

Comment: @ceejayoz i just stuck in this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $uname = $row["username"];
    $email = $row["email"];

    echo "<tr><td>$uname</td><td>$email</td></tr>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've converted your other calls to return `$result` as a `mysqli_result` object, the most efficient way to do this would probably be

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo "<tr><td>{$row['username']}</td><td>{$row['email']}</td></tr>\n";
}
```